# Get Filename of workbook in same folder

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the filename of a workbook in the same folder, but I'm running into problems using `ThisWorkbook.Path` to define the folder structure.

I've tried the below, but I get

> Runtime Error 52 - Bad file name or number

```vb
Sub WorksheetImport()

Dim vWBFolder As String
Dim vWBName As String

vWBFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path
vWBName = Dir(vWBFolder & "*.csv*")

MsgBox vWBName

End Sub
```

It works if I define the folder manually  e.g. - `vWBFolder = "D:\\TestFolder\\"`

---

The below answer is correct. Adding the \ should have fixed the issue.

Looks like my organization recently started backing up certain folders to OneDrive. This appears to have caused the error. Once the folder was excluded from OneDrive backup it worked as expected.

Comment: Right, so it looks as if `Dir` doesn't work with OneDrive folders. I haven't tried this myself but you could try the `FileSystemObject`?

Comment: Good question - first time i've used FileSystem Object;

Sub WorksheetImport()

Dim vWBFolder As String
Dim vWBName As String

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

vWBFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path

vWBName = FSO.GetFileName(vWBFolder & "\" & "*.csv*")

MsgBox vWBName

End Sub

I'm just getting *.csv* in the message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook.Path` doesn't have a slash at the end of it, so you just need to add a slash:

```vb
vWBName = Dir(vWBFolder & "\" & "*.csv*")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Yes I tried that as well as;

vWBFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

vWBName = Dir(vWBFolder & "*.csv*")

but getting the same error!

Comment: Could you move your excel to a new folder path and try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Could you please use like this

Sub WorksheetImport()
    
    Dim vWBFolder As String
    Dim vWBName As String
    
    
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    
    'vWBFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path
    vWBName = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv*")
    
    MsgBox vWBName
    
    End Sub
```